# Fastlane update breaks ruby

Tags: ruby, fastlane

When I ran a fastlane script to build and upload an ionic app to Hockeyapp, I saw the following message:

```
# fastlane 2.105.2 is available. You are on 2.103.1.
# You should use the latest version.
# Please update using `bundle update fastlane`.
```

So I ran `bundle update fastlane`, which appeared to work fine, but when I tried running my fastlane script again, the following error appeared, which I've never seen before:

```
Non-system Ruby in use. This may cause packaging to fail.
If you use RVM, please run `rvm use system`.
If you use chruby, please run `chruby system`.
error: archive not found at path '/path-to-app/platforms/ios/appname.xcarchive'
** EXPORT FAILED **
```

I also saw an extra line appear in the build settings output, which has never been there before:

```
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/debbiefigg/Projects/QuickNurse/quick-nurse-app/platforms/ios/Quick Nurse.xcarchive
```

I've spent hours going round in circles trying to figure out how to solve this, but have drawn a blank.

Can anyone suggest why this happened and how to solve it?

Comment: What ruby _are_ you using? Updated your OS recently?

Comment: ruby v2.5.1 managed by rbenv. no os update, just a fastlane update from 2.103.1 to 2.105.2, which is what appears to have caused the problem. As I don't know much about ruby, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Seems the equivalent to what the error message says for `rbenv` would be `rbenv global system`. Have you tried that and then rerunning the lane?
(The error message you are seeing is not from fastlane as far as I could investigate)